# How can I made a Debian ports like repo?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Is there a way to have only a debian folder and build the package (downloading and unpacking the sources) automatic? I've seen uscan but it scans for new packages, it doesn't allow to have a fixed download URL string.

**Edit:**
I want to have a folder for every package and inside only the debian folder and I don't know how to do for automatic download the sources and package it. Fedora has spectools, Arch downloads the tarball specified on PKGBUILD, so I want the same on Debian

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please give more details. What do you mean by Debian folder, for example? Are you talking about the Debian packaging directory? Perhaps for clarity describe your use case, if you have one. The target `debian/rules get-orig-source` can be defined, as described in https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html (section 4.9). This can download the source for you. But I am just guessing at what you want.

Comment: Yes, it works. Put the answer here.

Comment: Well, I still think your question is unclear, but is the following what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question, if I understand it correctly, is:

> Given just a `debian/` directory, i.e. a directory containing just the Debian packaging files for a software package, is there a way to use those packaging files to download and unpack the sources for that software package?

The target `get-orig-source` in `debian/rules` can be defined, as described in
[Debian Policy Manual Chapter 4 - Source packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html) (section 4.9). If this target is defined, then the source can be downloaded by running the following command from inside the `debian/` directory.

```
./rules get-orig-source
```